# Web.config registration missing! in RadEditor in IIS 7.5

Tags: telerik, iis-7.5, telerik-editor

I am working with RadEditor. I have purchased premium controls pack.
Editor works fine but when we open a image manager it throw an error i.e.

```
Web.config registration missing!
 The Telerik dialogs require a HttpHandler registration in the web.config file. Please, use the control's Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help for more information: Controls > RadEditor > Dialogs > Introduction
```

My webconfig file code is :

```
<system.web>
 <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and i am using routing without MVC architecture with asp.net 4.0 framework. and in global.asax file code is here

```
 routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx");
```

ignore for telerik controls.

these all code works fine in visual studio and run site from visual studio.

but it throws error while we run this site in IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5.

and it shows a alert message and image manager page displays :

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
```

message

How to resolve this error?????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use my given code in you web.config and it will solve your problem.. just try it....

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI"/>
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"></add>
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"></add>
      <add verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression"/>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI"/>
    </httpModules>
```

and this....

```
 <modules>
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression"/>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ChartImage.axd_*" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx_*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
```

Comment: Your solution Worked for me. My configuration was ported from IIS6 and was looking like that before the change <add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" validate="false" />  <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />